# Explanation of a theorem of the topology generated by a subbasis

Tags: general-topology

In my one of lecture notes, it says that the Topology $\tau_S$ on a set $X$ generated by a subbasis $S$ is $\tau_S=\{u\subset X \mid u\text{ is the union of finite intersections of elements of }S\}$.

Could somebody explain what does it mean that $u$ is "the" union of finite intersections of elements of $S$.

Why is it not that $u$ is "a" union of finite intersections of elements of $S$?

Comment: Well given a collection of open sets, there is exactly one open set which we call their union. But I agree I think this is better worded with 'a' instead of 'the'.

Comment: @DanielRust : But we're not given a collection of open sets.  There are many different finite subsets of $S$ and there are many different collections of intersections of them, whose union could be taken.

Comment: It was probably capital $U$ in class - quite common for $U$ to represent open sets, rare for $u$ to.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I agree. You have to squint hard to get it to agree with the usual definition. Either change 'the' to 'a', or insert the phrase 'the union of [a collection of] finite intersections'.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Nope, it is $u$, not $U$ in this note...

Comment: I really don't see the distinction between "the" and "a" here. "The union of (sets of some form)" doesn't mean that there can only be one such union, only that the set can be expression this way in at least one way. Certainly, in casual speech, I wouldn't make any distinction between these two forms.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, I (and many other mathematicians) try to avoid any possible confusions that comes from "a" and "the". One would not discuss about this kind of problem if he/she is 100% sure that there is no danger of confusion when no confusion can result.

Comment: But there is no confusion here. "$7$ is the sum of two positive integers" is no more wrong that "$7$ is a sum of two positive integers." @Yk26

Comment: Most of the statements of the "four square theorem," for example, on Wikipedia, Mathworld, etc, say "any natural number can be represented as the sum of four integer squares." (There were a few that used "a", but "the" dominates, and nowhere is "the" interpreted differently than "a.")

Comment: There's a vast difference between clarity and pedantry. The way English is used in mathematics, there is no difference. No mathematician would ever use "as the..." in a statement to mean "uniquely as the...." Any mathematician who did so would be guilty of malpractice in English. @Yk26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it ought to say "$u$ is a union of finite interesections of members of $S$".

I.e. there is some set of such finite intersections whose union is $u$.

It's not a union of all members of the unique such set; rather for some one of many such sets, it is their union.

Answer (score 0):

Its just the way it is. You first take finite intersection of elements in the subbasis to get the basis (so that subbasis is contained in the basis), and then you take the arbitrary union of elements in the basis to get open sets (so that basis is contained in the topology).